# Having trouble writing a SQL Sub-Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me show the relationships of the tables and what I'm trying to find:

**Users** - one to many with **AccountManager**

**AccountsManager** - one to many with **Accounts**

**Accounts** - one to many with **Transactions**

```
Select * from Users U
JOIN AccountManager am on am.AccountManager Id = u.AccountManagerId
JOIN Accounts a on a.AccountManagerId = AccountManager.Id
JOIN Transactions t on t.AccountId = a.Id
WHERE COUNT(t.Id) = 0
```

Edit: Thanks to @Shmiel for pointing out the above join on `Transactions` is incorrect. Thankfully, the accepted answer clears that up.

**Users** one to many with **Variables**

I'm trying to find `Users` who have no `Transactions` **AND** no `Variables`.
I'm using SSMS and wrote the appropriate joins for the first four tables using `COUNT` at the end, but I'm not sure how to get those same `Users` who have no `Transactions` and then query if they also have no `Variables` as that's another join on `Users`. I believe it's just a subquery that I'm missing.

I'm open to any suggestions and hoping I'm just overthinking this one.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. If you `join` to a table you only get those that have values. If you want to get those users without transactions you can't use `join`.

Comment: @Shmiel Interesting, what should I use then?

Comment: `left join` `where id is null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an anti-join, which in SQL is done with a `NOT EXISTS`.

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM AccountManager am
    JOIN Accounts a on a.AccountManagerId = AccountManager.Id
    JOIN Transactions t on t.AccountId = a.Id
    WHERE am.AccountManagerId = u.AccountManagerId
)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Variables v
    WHERE v.UserId = u.Id
);
```

Don't be tempted to use `NOT IN`, it can cause [incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists).

You can also use a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` construct, but the query can be non-obvious, and the compiler often finds it hard to reason about.

Comment: That did it! I actually meant to have users WITH transactions but no Variables, but I worded the question incorrectly. Thanks to your example, it was as simple as turning first  Where to "WHERE EXISTS" and I appreciate the explanation! Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say _incorrect_ results, rather _different_, or perhaps _surprising_.

Comment: Incorrect as in: not what is expected for the query spec, and incorrect for most people's expectations.